# Turn button into toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
var hours =0;
var mins =0;
var seconds =0;


document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function(){
      startTimer();
});

document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
      clearTimeout(timex);
});


           
function startTimer(){
  timex = setTimeout(function(){
    
      seconds++;
    if(seconds >59){
        seconds=0;
        mins++;
    if(mins>59) {
            mins=0;hours++;
        if(hours < 10) {
            $("#hours").text('0'+hours+':')
        } else 
            $("#hours").text(hours+':');
                }
                       
            if(mins < 10){                     
                $("#mins").text('0'+mins+':');
            }       
            else $("#mins").text(mins+':');
                   }
    
                if(seconds <10) {
                    $("#seconds").text('0'+seconds);
                } else {
                      $("#seconds").text(seconds);
                    }
    
    
   
      startTimer();

  },1000);
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


          <span id="hours">00:</span>
          <span id="mins">00:</span>
          <span id="seconds">00</span>  
       

     
        
<button id="start"><i class="fas fa-play" style="color:#000"></i></button>

        
 <button id="stop"><i class="fas fa-pause" style="color:#000;"></i></button>
```

I'm trying to replace the Play and Pause buttons with **just one**. So when I click the button it changes to "pause" and when it's paused it changes to "play" like on a toggle, but I couldn't get that to work, only the Play button keeps working and the button icon doesn't change when I try to pause the timer.

**HTML:**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


          <span id="hours">00:</span>
          <span id="mins">00:</span>
          <span id="seconds">00</span>  
       

     
        
<button id="start"><i class="fas fa-play" style="color:#000"></i></button>

        
 <button id="stop"><i class="fas fa-pause" style="color:#000;"></i></button>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
var hours =0;
var mins =0;
var seconds =0;


document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function(){
      startTimer();
});

document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
      clearTimeout(timex);
});


           
function startTimer(){
  timex = setTimeout(function(){
    
      seconds++;
    if(seconds >59){
        seconds=0;
        mins++;
    if(mins>59) {
            mins=0;hours++;
        if(hours < 10) {
            $("#hours").text('0'+hours+':')
        } else 
            $("#hours").text(hours+':');
                }
                       
            if(mins < 10){                     
                $("#mins").text('0'+mins+':');
            }       
            else $("#mins").text(mins+':');
                   }
    
                if(seconds <10) {
                    $("#seconds").text('0'+seconds);
                } else {
                      $("#seconds").text(seconds);
                    }
    
      startTimer();

  },1000);
}
```

make the "play" and "pause" buttons into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively simple. You just need a `boolean` (often also called a flag) which indicates in which state the timer currently is: Running or not. Then depending on that you have to either start or stop the timer as before.

To change the icon you can use the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace) method on the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property of every [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

You'll notice I've changed your variable declarations from `var` to `let` which you should do by default as `var` is always a global variable which causes all kinds of problems once your programs get larger. Check out [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript) on the different methods to declare a variable.

```js
let hours = 0;
let mins = 0;
let seconds = 0;
let timer = 0;
let isRunning = false;



const startStop = document.getElementById('startStop');
startStop.addEventListener('click', function(element) {
  if(isRunning) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    isRunning = false;
    console.log()
    startStop.querySelector("i").classList.replace("fa-pause", "fa-play");
  }
  else {
    startTimer();
    isRunning = true;
    startStop.querySelector("i").classList.replace("fa-play", "fa-pause");
  }
});



function startTimer() {
   timer = setTimeout(function() {

    seconds++;
    if (seconds > 59) {
      seconds = 0;
      mins++;
      if (mins > 59) {
        mins = 0;
        hours++;
        if (hours < 10) {
          $("#hours").text('0' + hours + ':')
        } else
          $("#hours").text(hours + ':');
      }

      if (mins < 10) {
        $("#mins").text('0' + mins + ':');
      } else $("#mins").text(mins + ':');
    }

    if (seconds < 10) {
      $("#seconds").text('0' + seconds);
    } else {
      $("#seconds").text(seconds);
    }
    startTimer();

  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="hours">00:</span>
<span id="mins">00:</span>
<span id="seconds">00</span>
<button id="startStop"><i class="fas fa-play" style="color:#000"></i></button></button>
```